# "The network path was not found" exception when adding domain user to local administrators on one of two computers

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm not very experienced with PowerShell, but I'm trying to learn. I can't find a solution to this problem elsewhere, sadly.

This is my script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$DomainName = "OPMEIS"
$UserName = "ClientInstall"

$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*Server*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    try {
        $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/Administrators,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
        $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
    } catch [Exception] {
          echo $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

There are two computers in the domain: WORKSTATION1 and WORKSTATION2. They are pretty much identical. Weirdly, the script does what it's supposed to do in the first iteration (WORKSTATION1) (**EDIT:** I am pretty sure that someone else did it manually on this computer), but on the second iteration (WORKSTATION2), the following exception is thrown:

```
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "The network path was not found.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

The exception is caused by the AdminGroup variable.
This needs to be automated because the actual number of workstations is unknown. If there's a better method, I'm interested to hear, but it would be nice to get the script working.

Any ideas? Thanks...

PowerShell version (Windows Server 2016):

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  1770
```

**EDIT**
Breakthrough discovery: I need to append ".local" to WORKSTATION2, but not WORKSTATION1. Why could this be?

Comment: Try running the commands one by one.  It's difficult to tell if it can't find the AdminGroup vs the User based on the exception message.

Comment: It's AdminGroup.

Comment: Or just remove the `try` - `catch`, the way it is defined, it removes more value then it adds... (what error do you get instead?)

Comment: Your error message tells you your distinguishedName cannot be found.  Explore why it can't find `WinNT://WORKSTATION2/Administrators,group`

Comment: "It's AdminGroup", could be that the concerned PC is a different language? See: [Localized Names for Administrator Account in Windows](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13813.localized-names-for-administrator-account-in-windows.aspx)

Comment: It's better to use Group Policy to define members of the `Administrators` group (whatever its name) than to script it.

Comment: @iRon I removed the try-catch block before pasting the exception details.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 How do I investigate that? The computers are in an OU to which a GPO has been linked that has the _Allow inbound file and printer sharing exceptions_ setting set to Enabled.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The goal here is to add a domain user to the local administrators group of every workstation. It's not supposed to be a global domain administrator, if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Audiopolis - yes, you can do that using Group Policy, and would be the recommended method rather than a script, as it would be managed centrally and automatically by policy.

Comment: It should be just a matter of troubleshooting. For this, I would just place `Write-Host "WinNT://$computer/Administrators,group"` above the `$AdminGroup = ...` line. Or manually create a (reverse) list of computers `$computers = "WORKSTATION2", "WORKSTATION1"` You might also consider to try a complete different approach and use the new [`Add-LocalGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

Comment: Good suggestions. Will investigate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt the next code snippet:

```
gwmi -query "select * from Win32_Group where sid='S-1-5-32-544'" -computername $env:computername|fl -force
```

For reference:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/11/02/how-can-i-determine-the-name-of-the-local-administrators-group/

and

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/10/three-easy-ways-to-use-powershell-and-wql-to-get-wmi-data/